# How to get individual ID and number of Pass/Fail from array?

Tags: javascript, json, angular

Here is an array of data I have. I need a new array with unique id and number of individual Pass/Fail status. I am using angular 6.

```
[
{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"7","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"9","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"10","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"4","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"8","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"7","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"1","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"1","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"11","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"4","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},
{"id":"5","status":"Failed"}
]

//JavaScript code
```

I expect the output

```
[
{"id":"1", "Passed": "2", "Failed": "0"},
{"id":"2", "Passed": "5", "Failed": "0"}....and so on]
```

there should be 10 element in the output.

Comment: when failed value is 0?

Comment: When not mentioned. If mentioned increment it.

Comment: your expected o/p have key called "failed" when it is 0 is there any condition for that?

Comment: no, it does not have any condition. If "status" is mention as passed increment "passed" and leave the "failed" as 0. If it has "failed" increment the "failed" and keep the "passed" as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these way.

https://jsfiddle.net/o3016bh7/

Just saying there is a class for your {id, "Passed", "Failed"} and it can count the integers behind "Passed" and "Failed".

```
class PassFailCounter {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Passed = 0;
        this.Failed = 0;
    }

    addPass() {
        this.Passed++;
    }

    addFail() {
        this.Failed++;
    }
}
```

Just read in the data and remember it in a Hashmap, implied that id is unique.
After, JSON.stringify() back the .values() of the said map and you have the exact output you mentioned.

```
let str = '[{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},{"id":"7","status":"Passed"},{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},{"id":"9","status":"Passed"},{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},{"id":"10","status":"Passed"},{"id":"4","status":"Passed"},{"id":"8","status":"Passed"},{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},{"id":"7","status":"Passed"},{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},{"id":"1","status":"Passed"},{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},{"id":"1","status":"Passed"},{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},{"id":"11","status":"Passed"},{"id":"4","status":"Passed"},{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},{"id":"5","status":"Failed"}]';

let data = JSON.parse(str);
let map = new Map();

data.forEach(entry => {
    let exist = map.get(Number(entry.id));
    if(!exist) {
        map.set(Number(entry.id), new PassFailCounter(Number(entry.id)));
        exist = map.get(Number(entry.id));
  }
  entry.status == "Passed" ? exist.addPass() : exist.addFail()      
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(Array.from(map.values())));
```

Maybe not the shortest solution, but it works.

Edit:
Instead of

```
JSON.stringify(Array.from(map.values()))
```

you could also do

```
JSON.stringify(Array.from(map.values()), function(key, value) {
    if(isNaN(value)) {
      return value;
    }
    return value.toString();
})
```

if String type is important on output.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander Koch, This is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`import * as _ from 'lodash'`

```
let passItem = _.find(array, function (o) { return o.status == 'passed' }) 
let failItem = _.find(array, function (o) { return o.status == 'fail' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, only one simple iteration:

```js
let str = '[{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},{"id":"7","status":"Passed"},{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},{"id":"9","status":"Passed"},{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},{"id":"10","status":"Passed"},{"id":"4","status":"Passed"},{"id":"8","status":"Passed"},{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},{"id":"7","status":"Passed"},{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},{"id":"1","status":"Passed"},{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},{"id":"1","status":"Passed"},{"id":"0","status":"Passed"},{"id":"11","status":"Passed"},{"id":"4","status":"Passed"},{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},{"id":"5","status":"Passed"},{"id":"2","status":"Passed"},{"id":"5","status":"Failed"}]';

let data = JSON.parse(str);

let newData = {};

data.forEach(item => {

  // initial data if key doesn't exists
  if ( ! newData[item.id]) {
    newData[item.id] = { Passed:0, Failed:0 }; 
  } 

  // increment Failed or Passed value
  newData[item.id][item.status]++; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to do this:

```
const results = [];
data.forEach(item => {
   const foundItem = results.find(result => result.id === item.id);
   if (!foundItem) {
      results.push({ 
         id: item.id, 
         Passed: (item.status === 'Passed') ? 1 : 0, 
         Failed: (item.status === 'Failed') ? 1 : 0
      });
   } else {
      if (item.status === 'Passed') foundItem.Passed += 1;
      else if (item.status === 'Failed') foundItem.Failed += 1;
   }
});
```